# Removing all viewController with other views of instance in a loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, uiviewcontroller

I have tabs that show `webViews` and one tab that displays `viewController` with elements.
When i press the back button i remove all the `viewController`+other `views` with the `tags` i created them like this:

```
 imageGame *appDelegate = (imageGame *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *bgImage = (UIActivityIndicatorView*) [appDelegate.viewController.view viewWithTag:7];

[bgImage removeFromSuperview];
 [appDelegate.viewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and its working fine, but if i touch it again and again every time new instances are created with the same tag, but when i use my code to remove them its not removing all of them, probably only one of them...

How can i remove all them with that similar logic?

Answer (score 0):

Do this remove all webViews from viewController add below code:

```
 for (id subview in self.view.subviews) {
  if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIWebView class]]) //remove only buttons
  {
     [subview removeFromSuperview];
    // or use below to remove specific tag UIWebView
    if(subview.tag == 999){ 
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: tried that code, just replaced `self.view.subviews` with `appDelegate.viewController.view`, but i don't have the property `tag` when trying `if(subview.tag==999)`